# How do I include only last record in the response that contains associated records in Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord

this function works. However, instead of including all the rounds. I just need to include the last one. How would I do it? I looked into using :scope but haven't found anything useful. Please help, it's driving me nuts!

```
def get_games_list
    Rails.logger.info("get_games_list".colorize(:color => :white, :background => :blue))

    player_1_games = Game.includes(:rounds, :player_2).where(:player_1_id => params[:player_id], :is_valid => true)
    player_2_games = Game.includes(:rounds, :player_1).where(:player_2_id => params[:player_id], :is_valid => true)

    render json: {
      error_code: ERROR_NOERROR, 
      status: "ok", 
      player_1_games: player_1_games.as_json(
        :include => {
          :player_2 => {
              :only => [:id, :user_name]
          },
          :rounds => { 
            :only => [:id, :playing_player_id]
          }
        }
      ), 
      player_2_games: player_2_games.as_json(
        :include => {
          :player_1 => {
              :only => [:id, :user_name]
          },
          :rounds => { 
            :only => [:id, :playing_player_id]
          }
        }
      )
    }
    return
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a `:last_round` has_one association in the Game model.

```
class Game < ApplicationModel
  # ...
  has_one :last_round, -> { order(round_date: :desc) }, class_name: 'Round'
  # ...
end
```